# Multiplying 2 images on MatLab using for-loops

Tags: matlab, image-processing

```
k = imread('D:\Desktop\Sem 6\IP\kj.bmp')
kr = imresize(k,[360,360],'nearest')

y = imread('D:\Desktop\Sem 6\IP\yg.bmp')
yr = imresize(y,[360,360],'nearest')

for row = 1 : 360
  for col = 1 : 360
    sum = 0;
    for k = 1 : 360
      sum = sum + kr(row, k) * yr(k, col);
    end
    product(row, col) = sum;
  end
end
imwrite(product,'mulImage.bmp');
imshow(mulImage.bmp);`
```

---

Using for-loops to get the output in MatLab
Please help me out with this code, i am not getting an image output

Comment: What are you doing matrix multiplication or element-wise multiplication?

Comment: matrix multiplication

Comment: your multiplication is correct. just show the output image as `imshow(product,[]);`

Comment: `imshow(mulImage.bmp)` makes no sense. Please read the documentation to `imshow`.